# Finding avg response time using splunk query

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, logging, splunk, splunk-query

I have a log line stating

Received App information from Source and processed in ms: 467

Now I would like to find the avg response time for the app which would be avg values for the time received after ms: Can you please guide me how do I extract the value of time (ms) and then find average response time

Answer (score 3):

You can use Splunk's [rex command](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Rex) to extract new fields at search time.

Next, you will need to use the [stats command](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Stats) along with the `avg` function to get the average response time over all events.

Here is the full Splunk query:

```
| makeresults | eval _raw="Received App information from Source and processed in ms: 467"
| rex field=_raw "processed in ms:\s+(?<response_time>\d+)"
| stats avg(response_time)
```

[image: screenshot]